# Interpreting return value of function directly as an array

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to interpret the return value of a function directly as an array?

lets say i have a function:

```
function getArray()  {
  return array("foo", "bar");
}
```

instead of writing:

```
$array = getArray();
$var = $array[1];
```

i want to access "bar" directly somewhat like:

```
$var = getArray()[1]; //this causes an error
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is called array dereferencing and will be supported only as of PHP 5.4 (which is the upcoming PHP version).

For now you can use the [`list`](http://php.net/list) language construct:

```
list(, $var) = getArray();
```

If you need the value to pass it to some other function, you can still hack around the limitation (*this is just for reference, not something you should use*):

```
func(${'_'.!$_=getArray()}[1]); // using the $_ var
func(${!${''}=getArray()}[1]);  // using the $ var
```