# How to directly use an array returned by a function

Tags: php, arrays, function, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interpreting return value of function directly as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781360/interpreting-return-value-of-function-directly-as-an-array)

Is there a way I can use the following?

`$year = getdate()["year"];` ??

If my function returns an array, can I read the value without writing another line?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can't but it's coming soon. This is also a duplicate of several other questions. Will vote to close when I find a suitable one

Comment: @Phil This is now possible (I changed my answer), if OP doesn't accept mine or someones correct answer I think we should delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that without writing newline...

```
$year = getdate(); $year = $year['year'];
```

Since PHP 5.4 it is possible to do so:

```
function fruits()
{
    return array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
}

echo fruits()['a']; # apple
```

It is called **array dereferencing**.

Comment: I enjoyed your answer...

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but you know what the OP was asking. If you were going for comedy, put it in a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I know I answered `echo $year['year'] = $year = getdate();`, but that was wrong (wasn't thinking clearly) and I got the downvote, so I changed my answer. I can delete it though... @Josh, thanks :)

Comment: My apologies then. I thought you were just being sarcastic! Darn Internet and no tone!

Comment: Thanks for an update webarto.. I accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you bother about one line ?
Just do:

```
$yearprep = getdate();
$year = $yearprep['year'];
```

or just let the function return 'year'

Comment: +1 for being pragmatic. FYI `getdate()` is a [built-in function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php).

Comment: It was usability question. I knew I could do that...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a proxy function, if you want:

```
function getPiece($key = 'year')
{
    $tempYear = getDate();
    return $tempYear[$key];
}

echo getPiece();
echo getPiece('day');
```

Comment: `function getPiece($function, $key){$t = $function();return $t[$key];}` this might be better? +1 for idea.

Comment: @webarto: Good call, that would allow the use of any function, not just getDate();

Comment: Josh, I wanted to use this with some inbuilt functions. Thanks for your help..

Comment: @Moiz: As webarto alluded to, all you'd have to do is make the proxy function call a variably defined function, then you can use it to call any function- builtin or user defined.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It only takes one line.

```
$date = date('Y');
```

[See this codepad for results](http://codepad.org/gOZmEqdo)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

If you really want to do it in one line, you could use the [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) construct:

```
extract(getdate());
```

or as middus mentions, just use the date function

```
$year = date('Y');
```