# Is there any way to access an element of the resulting array directly after calling explode() function in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interpreting return value of function directly as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781360/interpreting-return-value-of-function-directly-as-an-array)

Is there any way to access an element of the resulting array directly after calling explode() function in PHP?

e.g.:

```
echo explode('-', 'a-b-c')[1];
```

would return `b`

Comment: I think it is possible in php 5.3.4

Comment: @DmitriSnytkine: Nope.  Not possible until php5.4.  Here it is in [php5.3](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q93M7O), and here in [5.4](http://codepad.viper-7.com/75VMlc)...

Comment: This has been asked at least 4 million times on SO before. Seriously, does it hurt to search before you ask?

Comment: @middus, this would be a tough one to search for.

Comment: @JohnCartwright First result for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=explode+array+index

Comment: @middus Let us bow down to your search prowess. My point is, looking at the terms you've used it would not be obvious to the majority of the users what you are looking for. I would have not though to use those specific terms.

Answer (score 4):

There currently is no support for this in PHP. I believe PHP 5.4 (which is in BETA testing right now) is going to support this though.

for now you would just have to break it in two lines:

```
$arr = explode('-', 'a-b-c');
$arr[1]
```

Comment: or you can convert these 2 lines into a function and use it in one line...

Comment: or $element = array_shift(explode('-', 'a-b-c'));

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with the stable release of PHP (5.3), but will be included in PHP 5.4. The [feature](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) is already marked as "implemented" in the [rfc list of the php wiki](https://wiki.php.net/rfc).